# How to use Android webview to download a text file

Tags: android, webview

I am having difficulty getting android webview to download a text file from my server application.   It seems like it may have something to do with the transfer protocol or session variables. The file downloads fine when using the web browser application, but does not work in my custom webview code.  In my custom code, a file is downloaded, but it is not the text file requested.  Instead it is the HTML code of the login screen.  The server exporter checks if the user is logged in before doing the export and redirects to the login screen if not.

Here is the webview downloader code:

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
mWebView.setDownloadListener(this);

@Override
public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
        String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {

    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
            Uri.parse(url));

    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();

    // Notify client once download is completed!
    request.setNotificationVisibility(
            DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

    final String exportFileName = URLUtil.guessFileName(
                            url, contentDisposition, mimetype);
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, exportFileName);

    DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    dm.enqueue(request);
    // This is important!
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT); 
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE); // CATEGORY.OPENABLE
    intent.setType("*/*");// any application,any extension
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

On the server side, these are the headers used before the text file is generated:

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain" );
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$this->filename);
```

Comment: Does your download request need any auth? You manually have to set e.g. cookies in the new DownloadManager.Request.

Comment: Yes, the download does require authorization.  Could use a little more guidance on what needs to be done.

Comment: Eureka, your comment lead me to this answer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17929874/how-can-i-use-android-to-download-a-session-cookie-based-file-using-webview

Comment: Glad to give you a useful hint. You should accept your own answer to mark the question as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding cookies to the new DownloadManager.Request solved the problem.

```
    String cookie = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
    request.addRequestHeader("Cookie", cookie);
```